# jqxdropdownlist checkchange event

Tags: javascript, jqwidget

i am trying print jqxgrid dropdown list values using check boxes in jqxgrid i already bind the values in jqxdropdownlist in jqxgrid column but the problem when am trying to bind the vaules using checkChange event the checked value is printing but at the same time event firing multiple times i want to print one value at one time so please suggest me how to do this

i tried this code

```
{
    text: 'Sort Type', columntype: 'dropdownlist', datafield: 'aliasname1', width: '11%', editable: true,
    createeditor: function (row, cellvalue, editor, celltext, width, height) {

        // construct the editor.   var requiredfield =
        var requiredfield =
            [
                 "Ascending", "Descending", "Unsorted"
            ];
        editor.jqxDropDownList({
            checkboxes: true, source: requiredfield, autoDropDownHeight: true, selectedIndex: -1
        });

        $(document).on('checkChange', function (event) {

            var checked = event.args.checked;
            var colvalue = $('#shipmentgrid').jqxGrid('getcellvalue', row, 'column');
            var tblvalue = $('#shipmentgrid').jqxGrid('getcellvalue', row, 'table');

            if (checked == true) {

                var textareavalue = $("#txtQueryList").val();
                var sortvalues = textareavalue.split('ORDER BY ');
                var aa = sortvalues[1];


                if (aa != undefined) {

                    var bb = aa.split(',');

                    for (i = 0; i < bb.length; i++) {

                        if (bb[i] != "") {

                            try {
                                var s = bb[i];
                                var t = s;
                                if (colvalue == t) {

                                }
                                else {

                                    var  ee = textareavalue + "," + colvalue;
                                    $('#txtQueryList').empty();
                                    $("#txtQueryList").append(ee);       
                                }

                            }
                            catch (ex) {

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                else {
                    $("#txtQueryList").append("\n", "\n", "\n", "ORDER BY", " ", colvalue);
                }     
            }

            else {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add 'checkChanged' event handler to editor object, not document

```
editor.on('checkChange', function (event) {
```